# Using RAM android app

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

When developing an application that seen in the column "Maximum Memory Used" shows 231 MB. But Android Minitor at work shows that more than 40 MB application does not use. Whom to believe? Because of what used 231 MB?

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: The clue is in the title. It indicates that your app has used 231MB at one point of its lifetime. The Android Monitor shows its current usage.